# Sympy Stats: ValueError: not an integer ​

Tags: python, sympy, binomial-cdf

I am trying to manipulate binomial distributions algebraically. Specifically, I would like to get the expected value and standard deviation of a random variable:

```
import sympy
import sympy.stats
from sympy import *

a = sympy.Symbol('a', integer=True)
W = sympy.stats.Binomial('W', a, sympy.S.Half, +1, -1) 
print (W)
print (sympify(a).is_integer)

sympy.stats.E(W)
```

which outputs

```
W
True
```

then throws `ValueError: a is not an integer`.  I wonder what i am doing wrong here.
​

Comment: try 'integer=True' instead of the capitalized version

Comment: Now the output is "W" \n  "True", and then `a is not an integer'.  Thanks, but still stuck.

Comment: Use "isinstance(simpify(a), int)"  instead of ".is_integer"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I copy and paste your code into a current master I get

```
Sum(Piecewise((2**(-_k)*2**(_k - a)*_k*binomial(a, _k), (_k >= 0) & (_k <= a)), (0, True)), (_k, 0, a))
```

Perhaps you are using an older version of SymPy.